# How to straigthen the twine curls/wraps

Tags: threading

I have a thread cone like this

[image]

which I need to load into net needle.

[image]

The issue is after I have pulled some thread from the cone, the thread becomes too curly and tangled, it tries to wrap around it self. Is there any easier way to straighten the thread?

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a home improvement question.

Comment: But, @isherwood, it has the same answer as "how do I keep my wire from kinking when I pull it off the spool"... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Put the cone on a spindle so it unrolls/unwinds, rather than pulling it off the end.

Comment: It's the only way.

Comment: Show us some of your work :-)